# selecting/highlighting text with a different color

Tags: css, highlight

How do I change the colour of highlight/selection of text? The default is blue.

For example, if you highlight/select the text on this site, it is blue. But on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/) if the text is highlight/selected, it is orange peach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
::selection {
background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

as it is explained in here:

http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 2):

It's a CSS3-only feature, that only Firefox and Safari have implemented so far (as far as I know).

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Embarrassingly, I wrote that from Opera and I saw it working.  Doh!

Answer (score 1):

with JS you checkout where the selection is. then you remove it and change the css background-color of the selected text part in to orange ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you read the css-tricks article on the subject: :-)

http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
::selection {
    background: red;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: red;
}

::-webkit-selection {
    background: red;
}
```

webkit selection fixed opera issue :)