# JQuery/JavaScript - highlight a part of text from input or textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to highlight a part part of an Input text field in HTML using Javascript or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341843/how-to-highlight-a-part-part-of-an-input-text-field-in-html-using-javascript-or)

Does anyone know how to highlight some text in `input[type=text]` or `textarea`?
Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "highlight text"? Just have it in a different color or select the text?

Comment: I've tried replace text, which I want to highlight, with <span> element with background-color style. But after that input has this text with <span> elem directly

Comment: if you just want to select the text use this  `$('input[type=text]').select()`, or if you need background highlighting use `$('input[type=text]').css('background-color', '#FF0')`.

Comment: @Felix Kling I want to simply set background color for part of input text

Comment: @Mirek my answer highlights the text soon after clicking the button. if you want to highlight it during entering,simply use `css` styles like `color` and `background-color`

Comment: @FelixKling That's not what he wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place a `div` behind your `textarea` and then style it according to it's text.
**Notes**:

- Set your `textarea` `background-color` to transparent to see your `highlighter` color.
- Your `highlighter` have to be the same style and text content of your `textarea` to put the `span` on the right place.
- Set your `highlighter` text to the same color of it's background or you'll see a `<b>` effect, the same for the `span`.

**html**:

```
<div class="highlighter">some text <span>highlighted</span> some text</div>
<textarea>some text highlighted some text</textarea>
```

**css**:

```
.highlighter, textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: 'verdana';
}

.highlighter {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: white;
}

.highlighter span {
    background: red;
    color: red;
}

textarea {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/9Y99F/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need:) But it works correctly only if textarea has no scroll bars

Comment: @Mirek Yes, I know, you have to do some workaround to scroll highlighter together when you scroll textarea.

Comment: If you'd like this in plugin form (that also works with scrollbars), check out: https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-highlightTextarea

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet shows you how:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    // Select a portion of text
    createSelection(message, 0, 5);

    // get the selected portion of text
    var selectedText = message.value.substring(message.selectionStart, message.selectionEnd);
    alert(selectedText);
};

function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
    field.focus();
}
```