# Highlight text in text area, from moveover on DataTable

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery datatable, that display a search string column. When the user hovers over the row, I want to highlight the corresponding text within a text area.

For example, if the text area contains the following:

> this is a place of beauty

And my Datatable row contains:

> this is a place

then the text area portion needs to be highlighted.

I've used a couple of plugins, but they only seem to cater, for single word matches, whereas I need to do a sentence search, if you will.

The code I have is :

```
  $('#tblHitData tbody').on('mouseover', 'td', function() {

        var data = oHitData.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

        var searchString = data['SearchString'];

        if ($("#message:contains('" + searchString + "')")) {
            $('#message').highlight(searchString);
        };

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a jQuery object:

```
$("#message:contains('" + searchString + "')")
```

Objects in JavaScript are always "truthy," so your `if` statement will always run.

Instead, you can use the `each` function on the selector itself.

**Update**

You can't use `:contains` on a textarea.  Instead, you can search for the string within the textarea's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var searchString= 'is a test';

$("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
});

if($('#message').val().indexOf(searchString) >- 1) {
  $('#message').css('background', 'yellow');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>this is a test</div>
<div>this might possibly be a test</div>
<div>let's give lois a test</div>
<div>this is most definitely a test</div>
<textarea id="message">
  this is a test
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yeah, searching on a div isn't the problem. The text is inside a textarea, for which I simply cant get it to work.

Comment: Oh!  Sorry I didn't associate "text area" with a `textarea` object.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, so this appears to set the entire TextArea yellow. Not the matching string.

Comment: In your example, the textarea is also completly Yellow. In my table I want to hover over some text, and highlight the matching text in the textarea, and only that text

Comment: You have a couple options:  1) Use a contenteditable div instead of a textarea;  2) Place a div behind the textarea and style it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005057/jquery-javascript-highlight-a-part-of-text-from-input-or-textarea