# AngularJS - Not able to get value from factory service

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am very much new in AngularJS and due to which I am facing an issue and not able to understand the exact problem. The code which I tried is worked in normal javascript code but now I want to use custom service (factory function). Actually, I have a textarea where user can input their text and then they can do the formating by selecting any of the text. (discovertheweb.in/woweditor - this is existing site which I have created now I want to apply angular in this code). Now, I have created a custom service to check whether the user select any content or not. I have used the below code in my custom services and try to get the selection start, end point so that I can get the selected text from the textarea field. But, the problem is that I am getting 0 value for both selection start and end point. When i used the same code inside directive it works but try to get the value through service it is showing 0 for both. Please find the below code and let me know the code which I missed out here.

Custom Service:

```
(function(){
"use strict";
var wsApp = angular.module("WorkApp");
wsApp.factory("InputCheckService", function(){
    var defaultText = document.getElementById("input-text-area");                   
    var selStart = defaultText.selectionStart;
    var selEnd =  defaultText.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText;
    if(selStart != selEnd){
        selectedText = defaultText.value.substring(selStart, selEnd);                            
    }else{
        selectedText = null;
    }
    return {            
        selStart: selStart,
        defaultText: defaultText,
        selEnd: selEnd,
        selectedText: selectedText
    };
});
```

}());

The directive where I called this services. I already included the service inside the main controller in different file.

```
(function(){
"use strict";
var wsApp = angular.module("WorkApp");
wsApp.directive("generalDirective", generalDirective);
function generalDirective(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller:function($scope, InputCheckService){
            $scope.collapsed = false;
            $scope.CollpasePanel = function(){
                $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
            };
            $scope.updatePara = function(){
                alert(InputCheckService.defaultText+"Selection start: "+InputCheckService.selStart+" Selection End: "+ InputCheckService);
                /**
                 * defaultText: defaultText,
                    selStart: selStart,
                    selEnd: selEnd,
                    selectedText: selectedText
                 */
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'directive/general-directive.html'
    };
}
```

}());

If you need any more details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestion.

Regards, 
Robin

Comment: The complete website which I missed to mentioned, it is discovertheweb.in/woweditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use service to manipulate `DOM` element. You should manipulate `DOM` only at `directives`. Your problem is you **DONT** have anywhere to listen to **TEXTAREA SELECTION EVENT** and your service will not update the data inside. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/fojpzzxd/) for your problem. The `watchSelection directive` is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099851/bind-to-text-highlighting) from stackoverflow. Something you should notice :

1. I use service only to store data. Something like `selStart`, `selEnd` or `paragraphContent` and provide some `API` to retrieve the data

   ```
   .factory("InputCheckService", function () {
           return {
                  setSelStart: function (start) {
                       selStart = start;
                  },
                  .....
           },
   });
   ```
2. On the `watchSelection directive`, you `watch` for the `mouseup` event and will perform `update` the `service` so that it will store value you need and later you can retrieve it from other `directives` or `controllers`.

   ```
   elem.on('mouseup', function () {

       var start = elem[0].selectionStart;

       //store it to the service
       InputCheckService.setSelStart(start);
   });
   ```
3. In your `generalDirective directive` you can get value from your `service` and `angular` will auto update the view for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now, I am able to get all the values and do the require action through the said process. Thank you again.