# How to highlight text inside an input field?

Tags: html, css

Developing an application where I must highlight characters inputted in an `input[type=text]`. Characters can be `spaces` and `tabs` too. That is a reason I do not want to give a color to a text, but a background color, so that my users know that there's something written inside an element.

I have got nothing to aid you answering, but the hand-made picture of what I want to achieve and a jsfiddle link where I will try along with people who don't mind helping me [achieving](http://jsfiddle.net/dnatsvlishvili/b3w9s/) my goal for free.

[image: What I want to achieve with my question]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### `::first-line` pseudo-element <sup>(for Webkit browsers)</sup>

One option is using [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) pseudo-element, as follows:

```css
input[type="text"]::first-line {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b3w9s/1/)**.

I should note that this **only** works on **[*Webkit* web browsers](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/b97091a7e4bb4652d15fb652cb126ab374bd5ec0)** including Safari, Chrome and Opera15+.

According to [CSS level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-line-pseudo):

> **[5.12.1 The :first-line pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#first-line-pseudo)**
>
> The `:first-line` pseudo-element can only be attached to a **[block
>   container element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes)**.

However [CSS level 3 spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#first-line) states that:

> **[7.1. The ::first-line pseudo-element](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#first-line)**
>
> In CSS, the `::first-line` pseudo-element can only have an effect when
>   attached to a block-like container such as a block box, **inline-block**,
>   table-caption, or table-cell.

Hence, based on CSS level 3 spec `::first-line` is applicable to `inline-block` elements. Since Webkit based web browsers display `<input>` element as `inline-block` we can use the pseudo-element on `input`s in order to select the text.

Whereas some other web browsers (including Firefox) display `input` as `inline` and this is why `::first-line` has no effect on `input` elements on such web browsers.

I've made up a tiny test to [show the computed style of `display` property of `input`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/68c97u6e/) element.

### Multiple `text-shadow` values

This doesn't seem to be a real solution, but we can fake the effect by using multiple `text-shadow` values as follows:

```css
input[type="text"] {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold,
                 0 0 50px gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b3w9s/2/)** *(Or something **[fancier](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b3w9s/4/)**)*

### *[Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)* `<div>` & `::first-line`

As an option, you can use `contenteditable` attribute for a `<div>` element, and use `appearance` property to apply the useragent default stylesheet of text inputs to the `<div>` element, as follows:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="text-input form-control">
    text with background-color
</div>
```

Then, you can use `:first-line` pseudo-element to assign the background color:

```
.text-input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 200px;

    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;

    white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-input:first-line {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b3w9s/5/)**

**Disadvantages:**

- You have to disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for the `<div>` element and/or submit the form by pressing that via JavaScript.

*jQuery version:*

```javascript
$('.text-input').keypress(function(e){
    if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Submit the form
    }
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b3w9s/6/)**.

- You have to get the content of the *content editable* `<div>` and assign that value to a hidden `<input>` element on submitting the form via JavaScript. For instance, check the link below:

  - [Using HTML5, how do I use contenteditable fields in a form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission/6247785#6247785)

### Redesign entirely by JavaScript

Finally, you can use JavaScript to create/adjust the **colored box** beneath the input element.

In this approach, we wrap the `<input>` by a `relative` positioned wrapper having a *zero-width* colored child and then we remove the input from document normal flow by using `absolute` positioning and put that over the colored box.

As we start typing in the text input, the same content will be inserted to the nether colored box, So the width of the colored box matches the width of the text.

And one more thing:

The input shouldn't have any border, background or even default `appearance`. And it's better to wrap the colored box itself by another element, and apply the proper styles to that element to make it look like a real input element.

*That's it!*

Here is [a sort of implementation](http://jsbin.com/wosob/1/edit) of the above logic using *jQuery [highlightTextarea](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-highlightTextarea)* [plugin](http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/). It may not look good for the `<input>` elements as it's designed for `<textarea>`s.

Comment: Great, I'm amazed. Do you mind telling how can it can work with Mozilla too? (FF >= 27.x)

Comment: I'm testing your answer using OSX and Firefox latest, it's not exactly working. I'll accept your answer but maybe you could confirm that it's my software issue, and it's fine with other systems?

Comment: @Davit Sorry for the late response. It seems this only work on Webkit based web browsers as `<input>` is an empty HTML tag. However, there are Javascript solutions to achieve the same effect. I'll keep looking for the reason and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll accept your answer now, and if you could find something then please update your answer. Otherwise, I'm very thankful to you!

Comment: @Davit Just updated the answer; Added more details and alternatives.

Comment: thank you a lot. I'll see if I can award a bounty to your answer. That's amazing what you did. I can't start bounty on SO today, but ASA it's available I'll check what I can do.

Comment: @Davit Don't mention it :) If you needed a hand (e.g. for implementing the JavaScript solution), just let me know.

Comment: +1 Personally, I like the `text-shadow` work around, and it does work (and looks pretty good) on Firefox. Not quite so good on IE.

Answer (score 1):

- For selecting the content of an input (with highlight), use: `el.select()`.
- For css manual highlight, see @HashemQolami answer.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. Otherwise edit the question, amiright?