# Select last three digits of input on focus

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is it possible to automatically select the last three characters of an input field when the field receives focus.

For example, the input field has the number "123456".  When the field receives focus, I want "456" to be selected so that I can type "789" and the input would then have the value "123789".

I'm using ionic 3.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field)  SO question, might help...

Comment: Or this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342003/495157 input.setSelectionRange(0, 3); input.focus()

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) is the documentation for `setSelectionRange()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the `ElementRef` which comes with a [warning](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) as its vulnerable to XSS-attacks. And are to be used as a last resort.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" #testInput (focus)="onFocus()">
    </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...  
export class TestPage{
    @ViewChild('testInput', { read: ElementRef }) input:ElementRef;
    private inputRef;

    constructor(){}

    ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.inputRef = this.input.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    }

    onFocus(){
        let length = this.inputRef.value.length;

        if(length > 3){
            this.inputRef.setSelectionRange(length - 3, length)
        }
        else{
            this.inputRef.select();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `setSelectedRange` does not work on `type="number"`.  I need the input to be of type number so that the number pad is presented to the user.

Comment: `type="tel"` works pretty well.  The number key pad is presented slightly different, but it's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2+**

```js
getLastDigits(value: string): number {
  let digits: string;
  let cutPoint: number;
  if (value.length < 3) return value;
  cutPoint = value.length - 3;
  digits = value.substring(cutPoint);
  return +digits;
}
```

That should do the trick. `this.getLastDigits(value.toString())` to convert number to string when passing the value.